# Django database access speed depends on host used in request

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am having performance/speed issues in a Python/Django/Postgres application. Specifically, the speed of database queries (via Django's ORM) appears to be related to the hostname used in the request to django. The examples I'm using use either `localhost` or the VM's hostname (`dev.virtual`). Using the hostname, performance is good, but using `localhost` there is a significant slowdown (in the order of tens of times slower).

I've created a very basic view to test this:

```py
def generate_load_view(request, resource):

    length = int(request.GET.get("length"))
    length = 2 ** length

    iterations = int(request.GET.get("iterations"))
    iterations = 10 ** iterations

    if resource == "compute":
        load_generator = generate_compute_load

    elif resource == "memory":
        load_generator = generate_memory_load

    elif resource == "database":
        load_generator = generate_database_load

    else:
        raise Http404()

    t_start = time.monotonic()
    load_generator(length=length, iterations=iterations)
    t_end = time.monotonic()
    t_elapsed = t_end - t_start

    response = {"time": t_elapsed}
    return Response(response)

def generate_database_load(length, iterations):


    model = django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType

    pks = model.objects.values_list("pk", flat=True)
    for _ in range(iterations):
        random_pk = random.choice(pks)
        random_obj = model.objects.get(pk=random_pk)
```

I'm using django's `ContentType` object out of convenience.

The database (PostgreSQL) is running in a docker container on the same machine. I've used both django's development server (via `manage.py`) and a `gunicorn` server with no appreciable change.

To reiterate, if I make a request to `http://localhost/generate_load/` it is slow, but if I make a request (to the same running application, i.e., the app is not reconfigured or even restarted) to `http://dev.virtual/generate_load/` is is significantly faster. In both cases, the requests are made from the same VM (i.e., the same machine that the django application and the DB are running on).

Even when retrieving a single DB object, there is a large proportional difference, which seems to scale with the number of objects retrieved.

My tests randomise the hostname (e.g., in making 10 requests to each, the sequence is random, not all of one first, then the other).

Also, I've looked at the response times via custom django middleware that measures the request time within django (i.e., the time between the request being received and just before the response is returned), so this isn't related to the speed at which the app receives or returns the request (i.e., network speed between client and app).

It seems that substituting `127.0.0.1` for `localhost` doesn't change this, so I don't think it's related to issues resolving the `localhost` name. I've tried adding entries to `/etc/hosts` to see if that might change things:

```
127.0.0.1      inside
10.20.254.201  outside
```

The `outside` IP is what `dev.virtual` resolves to. The behaviour is the same, in that `inside` is slow, `outside` is fast.

I have tried changing the DB connection string to use alternative hostnames for the DB (e.g., both `localhost` and `dev.virtual`), and also tried changing the django app's `SITE_DOMAIN`, but this didn't change things.

I would *greatly* appreciate any assistance in understand and resolving this.

Comment: Are you using django debug toolbar?

Comment: @Tonio Yes, I am (or at least, I have it enabled). I think you've solved it: requests targetting an address that is one of `django-debug-toolbar`'s `INTERNAL_IPS` set all see the slowdown. I don't think I would have thought to look there, so thank you _immensely_! If you can, why not put your response as an answer (with any details you might know that explain what's going on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most comon thing that can change the behaviour in a Django project  depending on the IP addres is the Django Debug Toolbar.

In the documentation ([Performance considerations](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#performance-considerations)) you can read:

> The Debug Toolbar is designed to introduce as little overhead as
> possible in the rendering of pages. However, depending on your
> project, the overhead may become noticeable.
> In extreme cases, it can make development impractical.

In my worsts scenarios, I obtained a response time about 50 times slower with the Debug Toolbar. To reduce the overhead, you can play around the settings described in that docs. I got the best results disabling the stack-traces in the SQL and cache panels, the template context and removing the redirects panel:

```py
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'ENABLE_STACKTRACES': False,
    'SHOW_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT': False,
    'DISABLE_PANELS': [
        'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    ]
}
```

Anyway, **It should be fully disable in production** mode with the `DEBUG = False` setting.